# How Can I install adobe illustrator CC 2021 in Ubuntu 20.04 or 20.10?

Tags: system-installation, playonlinux

When I am trying to install Adobe CC 2021 through playonlinux, everytime I get error saying Window 10 is minimum requirement. So I just want to know how can I install adobe illustrator CC 2021 in ubuntu 20.04. Please tell me if you know as soon as possilble.

Comment: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=39717